# (Windows) How to enter password that is prompted after a command is executed in bat file?

Tags: git, batch-file

Basically I'm trying to create batch file to do git pull, enter password and then invoke protractor run command

But i'm struck after git pulling as it prompts for password. So how do i enter password dynamically? Can anybody help? 
Also please don't suggest the git cache way as i already tried and it didn't work for me and entering password would be the right thing to do

Comment: post your batch script

Comment: This might help https://superuser.com/questions/585398/bash-sending-simulated-keystrokes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but you can pass arguments to batch file like

`>myFile arg1 arg2`

and then use them inside script. With `%1` `%2` you can access first argument, second, and so on.